# How To Let VM recognize devices plugged into WYSE Tx0D

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, dell, thin-client, wyse

I am trying to use a Logitech unifying receiver with a Dell Wyse Tx0D thin client. I can plug in the unifying receiver and connect both the keyboard and the mouse to it, and it works in both the WYSE OS and the RDP connection.

However, the RDP session does not recognize the devices in the device manager, therefor I cannot use the logitech SetPoint software on the VM. Is there a way I can pass through the USB devices so that the device manager can recognize them in the server 2008 rdp session?

Answer (score 0):

The Wyse redirect everything by default, but for wireless device it work in standard mode when redirected, you can't use a special software in the remote session.

By standard I mean the device will use the basic 4 possible wireless channel to talk to the dongle, you can't use any software like on a desktop to define another channel, thus breaking the 4 channel limit with the siftware and breaking the customization of the device button.

I no longer can't find te KB, but if I fall upon it I will update my answer, as this limitation is there too for wyse and xendesktop redirection, not only for RDP